# Sum record data into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query which returns qty in each of my branch. now the branch has two WH_subType as you see in the attached diagram i have attached. I want to sum the 2 subtype and show its available qty. how can i do it.[image]

my select query is like this

```
SELECT
dbo.WarehouseType.name                        AS Section,
dbo.WarehouseSubType.name                     AS WH_Type,
dbo.WarehouseSubType1.name                    AS WH_SubType,
dbo.Branch.name                               AS Branch,
(dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.actualQuantity - dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.reservedQuantity) AS AvailQty,
dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.tafsilId         AS Tafsil,
dbo.Tafsil.description                        AS Product_Name
FROM
dbo.WarehouseSubType
INNER JOIN
dbo.WarehouseType
ON
(
    dbo.WarehouseSubType.warehouseTypeId = dbo.WarehouseType.id)
INNER JOIN
dbo.WarehouseSubType1
ON
(
     dbo.WarehouseSubType.id = dbo.WarehouseSubType1.warehouseSubTypeId)
INNER JOIN
dbo.Warehouse
ON
(
    dbo.WarehouseSubType1.id = dbo.Warehouse.warehouseSubType1Id)
INNER JOIN
dbo.Branch
ON
(
    dbo.Warehouse.branchId = dbo.Branch.id)
INNER JOIN
dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity
ON
(
    dbo.Warehouse.id = dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.warehouseId)
INNER JOIN
dbo.TafsilLink
ON
(
    dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.tafsilId = dbo.TafsilLink.sourceId)
INNER JOIN
dbo.Tafsil
ON
(
    dbo.TafsilLink.targetId = dbo.Tafsil.id)
INNER JOIN
dbo.FinishProduct
ON
(
    dbo.Tafsil.id = dbo.FinishProduct.tafsilId)
INNER JOIN
dbo.Supplier
ON
(
    dbo.FinishProduct.supplierId = dbo.Supplier.tafsilId)
WHERE
WarehouseSubType1.warehouseSubTypeId IN (1,4)
group by dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.tafsilId
```

Comment: It is hard to figure out from your question what you want. For you haven't provided test data and desired output. But, it seems, that you need just `GROUP BY` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Comment: @Igor i need to group which col.

>>For you haven't provided test data
The test data is in the picture.

>>and desired output.
I want to add the AvailQty cell of the WH_subtype col of the product col in the same branch col.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal what do you mean Where is the rest of your table?

Comment: I need to GROUP BY Tafsil.id

Comment: the group by needs to be a sub query joined in its own right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a group by

```
SELECT SubType, SUM(qty) AS QtySum
GROUP BY SubType
```

Every grouped by column should be in your select. Note: for every column you group by it further sub divides the data

Update based on OP comment:
If you want other columns you need to do something like

```
SELECT s.WH_SubType,s.AvailQty, t.other_cols
from
(SELECT
dbo.WarehouseSubType1.name                    AS WH_SubType,
sum(dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.actualQuantity -    dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.reservedQuantity) AS AvailQty
FROM
table
GROUP BY
dbo.WarehouseSubType1.name) s
left join table t on t.dbo.WarehouseSubType1.name = s.WH_SubType;
```

For reference see this question: [How do I use "group by" with three columns of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072679/how-do-i-use-group-by-with-three-columns-of-data)

UPDATE 2:

```
SELECT
dbo.WarehouseType.name                        AS Section,
dbo.WarehouseSubType.name                     AS WH_Type,
dbo.WarehouseSubType1.name                    AS WH_SubType,
dbo.Branch.name                               AS Branch,
SumTable.AvailQty,
SumTable.Tafsil,
dbo.Tafsil.description                        AS Product_Name
FROM
dbo.WarehouseSubType
INNER JOIN
dbo.WarehouseType
ON
(
    dbo.WarehouseSubType.warehouseTypeId = dbo.WarehouseType.id)
INNER JOIN
dbo.WarehouseSubType1
ON
(
     dbo.WarehouseSubType.id = dbo.WarehouseSubType1.warehouseSubTypeId)
INNER JOIN
dbo.Warehouse
ON
(
    dbo.WarehouseSubType1.id = dbo.Warehouse.warehouseSubType1Id)
INNER JOIN
dbo.Branch
ON
(
    dbo.Warehouse.branchId = dbo.Branch.id)
INNER JOIN
dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity
ON
(
    dbo.Warehouse.id = dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.warehouseId)
INNER JOIN
dbo.TafsilLink
ON
(
    dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.tafsilId = dbo.TafsilLink.sourceId)
INNER JOIN
dbo.Tafsil
ON
(
    dbo.TafsilLink.targetId = dbo.Tafsil.id)
INNER JOIN
dbo.FinishProduct
ON
(
    dbo.Tafsil.id = dbo.FinishProduct.tafsilId)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
sum(dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.actualQuantity - dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.reservedQuantity) AS AvailQty,
dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.tafsilId         AS Tafsil
FROM
dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity
group by dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.tafsilId) SumTable on dbo.Tafsil.id = SumTable.Tafsil
WHERE
WarehouseSubType1.warehouseSubTypeId IN (1,4)
```

Comment: i have edited my question and added the full query to make things more clear. I added the group by as you mentioned but i get error
" Column 'dbo.WarehouseType.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: see my update - you need to do a sub query to do the sum then join it back to the original table get the other columns

Comment: The multi-part identifier "dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.tafsilId" could not be bound. 2) [Error Code: 4104, SQL State: S1000]  The multi-part identifier "dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.actualQuantity" could not be bound. 3) [Error Code: 4104, SQL State: S1000]  The multi-part identifier "dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.reservedQuantity" could not be bound. 4) [Error Code: 4104, SQL State: S1000]  The multi-part identifier "dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.tafsilId" could not be bound.

Comment: I updated the query - I removed the supplier join because the supplier table is not used.

Comment: thanks,now I get another error Column 'dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.actualQuantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. 2) [Error Code: 8120, SQL State: S1000]  Column 'dbo.WarehouseProductQuantity.reservedQuantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: cheers,it worked but all its col sum is null.what could it be

Comment: @ZAJ sorry im not sure as I don't have the data - the concept described in my answer is the way to do it but you need to have a play around to get the data correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like

```
SELECT SUM(AvailQty), ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY WH_SubType
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: i added this  SUM(AvailQty) in my SELECT and in the GROUP BY i added this GROUP BY dbo.Tafsil.id  But I get error 
"Column 'dbo.WarehouseType.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. 2) [Error Code: 207, SQL State: 42S22]  Invalid column name 'AvailQty'."